# Error running tweepy on QGIS: No module named tweepy

Tags: python-2.7, tweepy, qgis

I went through all the previous questions on the subject but could not solve the problem.
I have installed tweepy through pip with no errors but got the error: "No module named tweepy" when I tried importing tweepy in QGIS. I uninstalled and reinstalled in the following directory:

> C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Scripts and still got the same error.

Than I reinstalled using "pip install tweepy". Now I can see the tweepy folders installed in both directories:

> C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Scripts and C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages.
>   I still get the same error.

What may the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

try to `pip uninstall tweepy`

and then again `pip install tweepy`

Check if you have tweepy folder here `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages`

[image]

And in **Qgis Python console** `import tweepy`

[image]

**Checked in Qgis 2.18.3**

Comment: I tried pip uninstall and pip install, but I do not see tweepy in this directory: C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages, but here: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages. The uninstall and re-install was done in this directory as well. What should I do?

Comment: copy this folder from C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages to C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages directly!probably you have the environment variables incorrect

Comment: import tweepy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler, AppAuthHandler
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)

Comment: File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\auth.py", line 9, in <module>
    from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session, OAuth1
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named requests_oauthlib

Comment: What is your qgis version?

Comment: qgis dektop 2.18.0 with grass 7.0.5